# Extending an existing jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, extend

I am trying to write a plugin that will extend an existing function in jQuery, e.g.

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.css = function()
    {
        // stuff I will be extending
        // that doesn't affect/change
        // the way .css() works
    };
})(jQuery);
```

There are only a few bits I need to extend of the `.css()` function. Mind me for asking, I was thinking about PHP classes since you can `className extend existingClass`, so I'm asking if it's possible to extend jQuery functions.

Comment: what will you be adding?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Sure... Just save a reference to the existing function, and call it:

```
(function($)
{
    // maintain a reference to the existing function
    var oldcss = $.fn.css;
    // ...before overwriting the jQuery extension point
    $.fn.css = function()
    {
        // original behavior - use function.apply to preserve context
        var ret = oldcss.apply(this, arguments);

        // stuff I will be extending
        // that doesn't affect/change
        // the way .css() works

        // preserve return value (probably the jQuery object...)
        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way but a little different than the best answer of this question:

```
// Maintain a reference to the existing function
const oldShow = jQuery.fn.show

jQuery.fn.show = function() {
  // Original behavior - use function.apply to preserve context
  const ret = oldShow.apply(this, arguments)

  // Your source code
  this.removeClass('hidden')

  return ret
}
```