# Following a function with (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, extension-methods

Here is an example of a function that is followed by the jQuery function:

```
<script> 
    (function ($)
    {
        $('a').mouseenter(
        function () { alert(this.id); });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I have done tons of searches and been reading through [jQuery Succinctly](http://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/jquery), but I'm really struggling to understand what passing in the `$` sign or following the function with `(jQuery)` does. Could anyone clarify this for me?

*Bonus question*: does this have anything to do with extending a jQuery method? I am looking into trying to extend the `.html()` method.

Comment: For the bonus: [Extending an existing jQuery function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007279/extending-an-existing-jquery-function)

Comment: This is exactly the same as `var a = function($){}; a(jQuery);`, but you are just not saving the function in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct is known as an IIFE - [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). The result of the expression inside the first set of parens is a function that takes one parameter (named `$`). The second set of parens then immediately invokes that function passing in the jQuery object.

It's a common pattern used to avoid polluting the surrounding (or global) scope.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is an function which takes a parameter called $.
Then you are calling that function and passing it jQuery as the parameter.
This allows you to use $ as shorthand for jQuery *inside that function*. It is useful when for whatever reason, you can't use $ shorthand everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the package jQuery in as the parameter to the function, to ensure that $ is an alias for jQuery.

Comment: is there anytime `$` would not be an alias for jQuery? Is this scope-related?

Comment: @JacobStamm Often in CMS like Joomla or Wordpress, `$` will not be jQuery. Hence, that closure is useful if you do not want to write jQuery every time. Also, when creating a plugin, you should always have a closure like that in case the developer using your plugin override `$`

Answer (score 0):

The dollar symbol (`$`) is an alias for the `jQuery` object that is passed in to the Immediately Invoked Function Expression. It could just as easily be a different character.

Here's a little example:

```js
/* 
 Here's my huge library akin to jQuery's (albeit with slightly less functionality). 
 */
function MySuperLibrary(){
    this.foo = function(bar){alert(bar);}
};
var msl = new MySuperLibrary;//a new instance of My Super Library

/* 
 Here I'm Immediately Invoking a function and passing the msl instance to it.
 I've used the 'X' character for its namespace within the closure in the same way as jQuery uses a $.
 */
(function(X){
    X.foo("foobar");
})(msl);
```