# Cannot extend an existing jQuery Function from within a child-theme.js

Tags: function, jquery, javascript, extend

### Challenge

**I am using a Theme which comes with a custom jQuery Infinite-Scrolling feature. I need to extend that jQuery-function to hook-in a refresh of my AddThis-Share Buttons, so that they get added to dynamically loaded posts while infinite scrolling.**

### Situation

The Theme I'm using includes by default a `/js/theme.js` file, containing a JavaScript-function `runInfiniteScroll()` which is triggered, when a user scrolls down on the blog's homepage. Here's the relevant excerpt from that `theme.js`-file:

```js
jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    // VARIOUS OTHER JQUERY FUNCTIONS

    /**
     * Infinite scrolling
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */
    // infinite scroll
    function runInfiniteScroll() {

      // start Infinite scroll
      $infiniteContainer.infinitescroll({
          navSelector : '.pagination',
          nextSelector : '.pagination .nav-links a.page-numbers',
          itemSelector : '.bwp-masonry-item',
          loading: {
            msgText: themeData.iScrollLoadingMsg,
            finishedMsg: themeData.iScrollFinishedMsg,
            img: loadingIMG
          },
          errorCallback: function () {
            // "No more posts to load" message
            if (themeData.iScrollLoadMoreBtn) {
              finishLoadMore();
            }
          }
        },
        function(newElements) {
          var
            newElementsId_str,
            newElementsId,
            tempIdArr = [],
            isSticky = false,
            stickyIdArr = [];

          // DO ALL THE DYNAMIC CONTENT LOADING
          // AND MANIPULATION/LAYOUTING STUFF HERE...

        } // end callback
      ); // end infinitescroll

    }

    // VARIOUS OTHER JQUERY FUNCTIONS

  });
});
```

In order to ensure future update-compatibility, I do not want to modify this existing theme.js-file, but activated a Child-Theme where I have a new `child-theme.js`-file (besides oder enhancements to the original theme).

### Solution approach

I thought about extending the required JS-functions by extending it in my “child-theme.js” file.

So I included the file “child-theme.js” via wp_enqueue_script() additionally on page load:

```php
// child-theme.js
wp_enqueue_script('my-child-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/child-theme.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
```

This works:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wordpress.local/wp-content/themes/main/js/theme.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wordpress.local/wp-content/themes/child-theme/js/child-theme.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wordpress.local/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7'></script>
```

### Issue

Where I do not succeed is with extending the original JavaScript function:

***ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: runInfiniteScroll***

In child-theme.js I have the following code:

```js
/**
 * Enhanced: Infinite scrolling
 * ----------------------------------------------------
 */
(function($){
        'use strict';
        console.log( 'child-theme.js loaded' ); // this works

        // maintain a reference to the original function
        var orig_runInfiniteScroll = runInfiniteScroll; // <= ReferenceError: Can't find variable: runInfiniteScroll

        // ...before overwriting the jQuery extension point
        runInfiniteScroll = function() {
            console.log( 'Executing enhanced runInfiniteScroll()-function' );
            // original behavior - use function.apply (or .call) to preserve context
            var returnObj = orig_runInfiniteScroll.apply(this, arguments);

            // AddThis buttons - add to dynamically loaded content
            addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox');

            // preserve return value (probably the jQuery object...)
            return returnObj;
        };
})(jQuery);
```

This Code Snippet - for overwriting a previously initiated jQuery function - is based on this stackoverflow.com question: [Extending an existing jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007279/extending-an-existing-jquery-function)

### Help needed

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, how I can extend the original function with custom code from within a `child-theme.js`-file? Is this even possible?

**Thanks for your help & suggestions!** ♥

Comment: In all honesty this looks like a pure javascript question that just happens to be in a WP context, perhaps this would be better suited on Stack Overflow? If I read it right you're trying to monkeypatch some infinite scrolling code that just happens to be in your parent theme

Comment: Thank you @Tom-j-Nowell & I agree, it could just as well be a plain JS/jQuery question. Will think about posting it on stackoverflow probably if no one can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your function to an object like $.fn.somefunctionname instead of declaring the function within the closure.  A function inside a closure isn't visible outside of the closure.  This will make it accessible from the jquery object.